# Deno: Importing a JavaScript module into TypeScript gives error

Tags: javascript, typescript, v8, deno

I have a TypeScript script that imports the `Xlsx.js` module as follows:

```
import {XLSX} from 'https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/master/lib/xlsx/xlsx';
```

This give the following error message:

```
Download https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/master/lib/xlsx/xlsx
error: Uncaught Other: Import 'https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/master/lib/xlsx/xlsx' failed: 404 Not Found   ► js/errors.ts:33:12
    at DenoError (js/errors.ts:22:5)
    at maybeError (js/errors.ts:33:12)
    at maybeThrowError (js/errors.ts:39:15)
    at sendSync (js/dispatch.ts:137:5)
    at fetchSourceFile (js/compiler.ts:134:19)
    at _resolveModule (js/compiler.ts:253:12)
    at js/compiler.ts:369:33
    at resolveModuleNames (js/compiler.ts:367:24)
    at resolveModuleNamesWorker (third_party/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:89230:127)
    at resolveModuleNamesReusingOldState (third_party/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:89473:24)
```

What am I missing? I am on Windows 10 x64 build 18912.1001, using Deno version 0.13.0
v8 version 7.7.200, TypeScript version 3.5.1

Comment: The error is crystal clear: "Not found".  You can see for yourself by copying that URL into an empty browser tab.

Answer (score 2):

When using Deno, you need to specify the whole extension of the file.

I believe you might want to do

```
import {XLSX} from "https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/master/lib/xlsx/xlsx.js";
```